# How to run Vaadin 7.3.9 Projects having IvyDE and Annotation servlet configuration with RunJettyRun in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, vaadin

Prior to the actual version of Vaadin (7.3.9) it was possible to create and run Vaadin 7 projects in a fancy way just using the RunJettyRun -> https://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/ plugin.

Now that Vaadin has migrated its configuration from web.xml to annotations (Java Servlet API 3.0), I noticed that if I deploy a Vaadin 7 project created with the `vaadin 7 eclipse plugin` **New Vaadin 7 Project wizard** (the one which uses Ivy as the dependency manager and build automation tool, below a screenshot of the project structure):

[image]

When I select *Debug as -> Run Jetty* and run the project, I get a 404 Not Found either for the http://localhost:8080 or for the http://localhost:8080/project-name URLs.

I can use Tomcat, but sometimes the deployment gets really really slow, Tomcat hangs and every time I deploy a new project in Tomcat I need to restart it before the new project can be ran on the server. With Jetty local deployment is simpler and faster IMHO.

I can also use Jetty together with Maven, but I need to work with Ivy, i.e. create Vaadin projects through the plugin's wizard.

How can I still use the Jetty speed when I develop a Vaadin 7 application now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new Vaadin 7 Project with Servlet API 3.0 using the wizard
2. Resolve dependencies and compile everything
3. Select Run as/Debug as -> Run/Debug Configurations
4. Select Jetty Webapp -> New launch configuration
5. Select a Jetty Version: -> **8.x or newer (required for Servlet API 3.0)**
6. Hit Run/Debug

Comment: Thank you for the resp. Which Run Jetty Run `updatesite` for the plugin did you use? `http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite/`?

Comment: That's the updatesite I'm using, I'm running version 1.3.3.201203161919.

Comment: Sorry for being absent for a while, your step by step description worked great! Thank you! Just another question, is there a way to make Jetty automatically publish the subsequent changes made to the code in order to not re-run the application over and over?

Comment: In the Jetty launch configuration there's a tab called "Source Monitor List" where you can check "Enable Scanner" to automatically restart Jetty on file changes. Remember to have Eclipse build your project automatically on changes.

Comment: I saw that the changes apply only per-project, is there a way to set the "Enable Scanner" option globally for all projects and for the new projects that I will create? Or do I need to always check "Enable Scanner" for every project I create? Also can I set the default Jetty version from 6.x.x to 8.x.x globally?

Comment: Launch configurations are per-project, so I don't believe there's any way to  enable scanner globally for all projects. You need to do that manually for each new project or you use the duplicate launch configuration button next to the "create new launch configuration" and then change the project that is used in the launch configuration.

Comment: All right, thanks for having removed my doubts! Anyway, It seems  I have found a way to set Enable Scanner for every new project which runs with Jetty, go to `Preferences -> RunJettyRun` and check `Default Enable Scanner when create new configuration`, it can be useful for you too! Setting Jetty version globally is not mentioned anywhere though.